# Efficiently create indexes in couchbase

Tags: indexing, couchbase

I have a huge database on which the users can query using multiple filters. I have about 10 filters which the user can use and multiple filters can be applied. What is an efficient way to create indexes based on this filters? Do I go about creating index for all possible combinations? If I go down that path what are the possible repercussions of creating too many indexes?

Comment: https://blog.couchbase.com/create-right-index-get-right-performance/ this might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a difficult question to answer without any knowledge of your system. Here are my recommendations:

**1)** Couchbase 6.5 has an index recommender, install it on your machine and run the most common queries there. It will give you the proper index for each one.

**2)** Once you have all the index recommendations, try to combine the ones with the same document type

**3)** You should have at least one index per document type

**4)** Remove your primary index from your production environment (once you have already at least one index for each document type)

**5)** Sorting is an expensive operation, consider storing the data in your index sorted already:

```
CREATE INDEX `us_users_sorted` ON
`user_profile`(
`countryCode`,
`firstName` DESC,
`lastName` DESC)
WHERE (((`type` = "user")
and (`enabled` = true))
and (`countryCode` = "US"))
```

**6)** Avoid **select *** whenever possible and use partial and cover indexes

**7)** If you have documents with too many fields to index, consider using adaptive indexes

The side effect of creating too many indexes is naturally a higher footprint in disk, cpu and memory. However, it depends on the size of your data and cluster.

If you have a cluster with >=5 nodes, you might also consider splitting the index and query from the data node.

Comment: Index recommended helped. Thanks (: